# SSRS Excel export, Row height not increased in excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In one of my SSRS Report, The cell is expanding properly in report but when the report is exported to Excel the single cell contain the whole text but I have to manually increase the row height in excel to make the whole text visible.

Is there any export option in SSRS where can tell excel to adjust the row height as per the data.

Comment: Just to check, how large is the row?  The Excel renderer has a maximum row height of 409 points.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what reports layout you have, but generally simply setting CanGrow=True should expand cell in Excel export. Probably you'll need to set CanGrow=True for all cells in the row. This will not work in case you have merged cells in the row.

See more info [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c0e105bb-2b9e-477f-8cec-602bff508d48/export-to-excel-2010-in-ssrs-can-grow-option-is-not-working-in-sql-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Comment: @Swapnil did this answer helped you?